# Verb (or expression) referring to something that happens suddenly and unexpectedly, and upsets you

Tags: expressions, idioms

I’m trying to find a verb or idiomatic expression to refer to something that happens suddenly and unexpectedly, upsets and overwhelms you like a bolt from the blue. For example, a shocking event in your life...

Comment: You could check this post: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/378378/a-word-phrase-for-an-unexpected-change-or-turn-of-events-in-a-persons-life

Comment: bolt from the blue!

Answer (score 3):

The idea of some sudden, unexpected and upsetting thing is expressed by the verb ***TO BLINDSIDE***.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blindside:

***BLINDSIDE***

transitive verb

1: to hit unexpectedly 
from or as if from the blind side

// blindside the quarterback

2: to surprise unpleasantly

// We were all blindsided
 by the news of her sudden death.

Cambridge Dictionary https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blindside?q=BLINDSIDE+
gives the similar definition of '***TO BLINDSIDE***' :

- to surprise someone, 
  usually with harmful results:

// The recession blindsided a lot of lawyers who had previously taken for granted their comfortable income.

Comment: You should put such quotations in > block quotes.